# MYSQL SubQuery with Max

Tags: mysql, subquery, max

I running into some time  issues using my simple select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ltowert  
WHERE bat = 3   
  AND id >= (SELECT id  
             FROM ltowert 
             WHERE bat = 3 AND ident = 'v0' 
             ORDER BY id DESC
             LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY ident;
```

It takes nearly 12 seconds (depending on the index, etc..)

If I run the subquery (0.00075 sec) and put the result in the statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ltowert  
WHERE bat = 3  AND id >= 20979399 
ORDER BY ident;
```

it runs in just 0.00095 sec, in addition: 0.0017 sec

So it seems, using the subquery avoid the Optimizer to use the index ?
How can I fix it and get quicker results ?

Thanks for any answers.

JR

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE ltowert`

Comment: How many rows are returned?

Answer (score 0):

I test your proposal, but I run into a problem of understanding. Maybe, it's my issue:

Your idea works, but the result is wrong: Result is only 1 row, but I expect 11 rows.  I expect all row from l1, where id **>**= l2.id.

So I changed to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ltowert l1
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT id 
            FROM ltowert 
            WHERE bat = 3 AND ident = 'v0' 
            order by id desc limit 1 
            ) as l2 on l1.id>=l2.id 
order by l1.ident;
```

This return much rows. l1.bat = 0 which is not the request.
Change to:

A. `") as l2 on l1.id>=l2.id AND l1.bat = 3"`

or

B. `WHERE l1.bat = 3`

runs into a timeout Error 2013.

What is my mistake ?

Additional, due to my 2 step tests, I do a test using a variable:

```
SELECT @ref_id:=id FROM  ltowert   WHERE bat = 3 AND ident = 'v0'  order by id desc limit 1; 
SELECT * FROM ltowert l1 where bat = 3 AND l1.id >= @ref_id order by l1.ident;
```

It is fast, and give the right results.
Is there a disadvantage to this usage?  (I know: 2 separate statements were not maintenance friendly)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Show us the `EXPLAINs` for them.

Answer (score 0):

You need both of these:

```
INDEX(bat, ident, id)
INDEX(bat, id)
```

If they don't suffice, please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE ltowert;
EXPLAIN SELECT ...;
```